# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.location/java.lang.String};

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-permissions, kotlin-android

I working on a flutter project which uses location services.
There is one case where user 'denied permission forever', that time i need to open app location setting to turn it on and for that i'm using native code of kotlin.
all code of native is working fine (checking using Log) but on `startActivity(Intent(this, Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS::class.java))`  it does not open that app location setting page and says the error

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.location/java.lang.String}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

anyone can help me get that specific location permission of my flutter app
(dont share about 'app info page, phone location page)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in `Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS::class.java` which calls the overloaded constructor `Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`.

What you are looking for is the constructor `Intent(String action)` where `Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` is the action.

The actual call should look like: `startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))`

Comment: Thanks for reply but it open location setting for all app not a single app, could u tell me how to open my app location setting where i can on/off